# How do I change the color for the Alternating row in ui-grid?

Tags: ui-grid

I am new to AngularJS. How do I apply the ng-class to the alternating row in ui-grid with `gridOptions`?

It is kind of like with

```
ng-repeat (ng-class="$odd ? 'odd' : 'even')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with custom css:

**Odd rows**

```
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(2n) .ui-grid-cell {
   background-color: //color you desire;
}
```

Comment: The following alternative also works:

    :nth-child(2n).ui-grid-row .ui-grid-cell-contents { 
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
      }

Answer (score 0):

You can change colors with CSS:

```
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Also you can obtain CSS and experiment with changing other ui-grid styles here:

http://ui-grid.info/customizer/